# sql: scan row(s) with unknown number of columns (select * from ...)

Tags: sql, go

I have a table `t` containing a lot of columns, and my sql is like this: `select * from t`. Now I only want to scan one column or two from the wide returned row set. However, the sql.Scan accepts `dest ...interface{}` as arguments. Does it mean I have to scan everything and use only the column I needed?

I know I could change the sql from `select *` to `select my_favorite_rows`, however, in this case, I have no way to change the sql.

Comment: It returns an sql.Rows reference. Use rows.Next to iterate until you have the row you want. http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

Comment: Thanks @elithrar. I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. My question is that I only want one column or two from a lot of columns. Is there any convenient way to do that? Either from column index or column name?

Comment: I don't think there is a convenient way to do this with the sql package. Possibly look at jmoiron/sqlx for some extensions to sql that  includes what you're trying to do. Otherwise, sql.Rows provides a Columns() function that you can use to identify the cols you want.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. jmoiron/sqlx looks promising. I personally prefer maps to structs. Maybe what I need is to find an efficient way to quickly dump a row to a map.

Comment: You can pass a map to sqlx just as easily as a struct. Is there a specific reason why you aren't specifying the columns as part of your query, though?

Comment: @elithrar sqlx seems to be the answer to my question. In my case, the columns from the SQL are dynamic, therefore I have no way to determine the columns names when I write the code. So I have to use map.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can make use of Rows.Columns, e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Vehicle struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Wheels int
}

// VehicleCol returns a reference for a column of a Vehicle
func VehicleCol(colname string, vh *Vehicle) interface{} {
    switch colname {
    case "id":
        return &vh.Id
    case "name":
        return &vh.Name
    case "wheels":
        return &vh.Wheels
    default:
        panic("unknown column " + colname)
    }
}

func panicOnErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := pq.ParseURL(`postgres://docker:docker@172.17.0.2:5432/pgsqltest?schema=public`)
    panicOnErr(err)

    var db *sql.DB
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", conn)
    panicOnErr(err)

    var rows *sql.Rows
    rows, err = db.Query("select * from vehicle")
    panicOnErr(err)

    // get the column names from the query
    var columns []string
    columns, err = rows.Columns()
    panicOnErr(err)

    colNum := len(columns)

    all := []Vehicle{}

    for rows.Next() {
        vh := Vehicle{}

        // make references for the cols with the aid of VehicleCol
        cols := make([]interface{}, colNum)
        for i := 0; i < colNum; i++ {
            cols[i] = VehicleCol(columns[i], &vh)
        }

        err = rows.Scan(cols...)
        panicOnErr(err)

        all = append(all, vh)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", all)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code @metakeule. I'm thinking this might be some starting point to further wrap these low level apis to make the Go's database access more usable. Go's sql api looks really ugly.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen  yes, it was meant as a starting point and to get better understanding of the sql api. please consider accepting the answer or voting for it.

Answer (score 3):

For unknown length of columns but if you're **sure** about their type,

```golang
    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    colLen := len(cols)
    vals := make([]interface{}, colLen)
    for rows.Next() {
        for i := 0; i < len(colLen); i++ {
            vals[i] = new(string)
        }
        err := rows.Scan(vals...)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error()) // if wrong type
        }

        fmt.Printf("Column 1: %s\n", *(vals[0].(*string))) // will panic if wrong type
    }
```

PS: Not recommended for prod

Comment: Had an issue with null values being returned, so simply replaced `vals[i] = new(string)` with `vals[i] = new(sql.NullString)`